# intellij community edition patch updates

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Tho IDEA & Android studio are based on the same platform, for some reason if I need to update IDEA community edition, I need to download the complete installable (~320MB). However, to update android studio, its hardly 10-30MB per patch.

Does anyone know how to do patch update instead of complete download in community edition?

Comment: From which version to which version are you updating? In IntelliJ IDEA, you can do patch updates if you don't skip versions (e.g. 2016.2.1 to 2016.2.2).

Comment: I was having a slightly older version of IDEA 2016 & I tried upgrading to 2016.2.2, it was taking me to full download page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IntelliJ IDEA, patch updates are only available for immediately adjacent versions. There is no way to perform a patch update if you skip versions - the patch required for such an update is simply not being built and published.

Comment: A reference to what? I was the developer who originally set up the patch building procedure for IntelliJ IDEA releases. The patches are built on our internal TeamCity server, so I can't send you a reference to that, sorry.

Comment: I was referring to a docs page reference (if you happen to know it). Thanks in any case..